# Lie Derivative Using Difference Quotient

Tags: differential-geometry

Calculate the Lie derivative of

$$G(x,y) \ = \ (x^2 \ + \ y,2y)$$

along

$$F(x,y) \ = \ (2x \ + \ 3y,5x)$$

using the definition

$$\mathcal{L}_F(G(\vec{x}_0)) \ = \ \ \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{(\theta_-t)_*(G(\theta_t(\vec{x}_0))) \ - \ G(\vec{x}_0)}{t}$$

First I calculated the integral curves of $F$ using $\theta'(t) \ = \ F(\theta(t))$

Thus $(x'(t),y'(t)) \ = \ (2x(t) \ + \ 3y(t),5y(t))$ becomes a system of ode's:

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
2 & 3 \\
5 & 0 \end{array} \right)\ \ \left( \begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \end{array} \right)\ \ = \ \left( \begin{array}{c}
x' \\
y' \end{array} \right)\ $$

The matrix has eigenvalues $-3$ & $5$ thus

$$\theta(t) \ = \ (Ae^{-3t},Be^{5t})$$

are the integral curves &

$$\theta(x,y,t) \ = \ (xe^{-3t},ye^{5t})$$

is the flow of $F$.

However when I plug this in to the formula & work through it I get stuck & have tried multiple different things all ending in nothing, either getting zero all the time (even when I know it's wrong after checking my answers with $[F,G]$ for different vectors, or else dividing by zero. How do you actually work though this thing?

Comment: I am not sure about the flow you computed: $x'=2x+3y$ and $y'=5y$ give $y(t)=B\exp(5t)$, but $x(t)=A\exp(-3t)$ does not satisfy the first equation...what am I missing?

Comment: The solution to the differential equation is $\theta(t)=(Ae^{2t}+Be^{2t}(e^{3t}-1),Be^{5t})$.